# Setting reduced Range for 3dprint

Tags: 3d-printing

Unable to set Range for 3dprint as part of full 3D parametricPlot3DRange.

> RevolutionPlot3D[{50 + 25*Cos[u], 25*Sin[u]}, {u, 0, Pi}, 
>        PlotStyle -> Thickness[3], PlotRange ->{ {0, 80} {-80, 80} {0, 20}}]
>
> ```
> Export["FileName.stl", %]
> ```

However stl reader shows the full Range in Ver 8. In it a version related problem?

EDIT1:

The following does not output an STL file.

> RevolutionPlot3D[{50 + 25*Cos[u], 25*Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi},
>   PlotStyle -> Thickness[3], PlotRange -> {{0, 80} {0, 80} {0, 20}},
>   RegionFunction -> Function[{{x > 0} && {y > 0} && {z > 0}}]]

Export["Octant.stl", %]

Please help.

Comment: In V11.3 it's gotta be worse: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DgWz4.png -- If I leave off `PlotRange` it works ok.  I don't have any way to help with V8 though.

Comment: Maybe use `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x >= 0]`?

Comment: Yes it works for one dividing plane, but not if multiple planes with $(x,y,z)$  limits 
 need to be  bounded

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  Multiple planes are no problem for me but I doubt I used the same code as you.  I get a much better plot with `PlotPoints -> 100` and the `PlotRange` is displayed correctly and exports to STL.  Maybe it will work in V8

Comment: Also wrong Boolean definition in the EDIT1 not working..